# d3.js brush() inherits incorrect height and width From svg parent using viewBox

Tags: d3.js, svg, viewbox

My root question is: is there a way to set the d3 brush window size so that it is properly inherited from its parent like the other SVG components when using viewBox?

Details:
I have two charts that are linked.  The first displays a set of line charts and the second is a basic chart that allows zooming on the primary chart.  It looks almost exactly like this example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

I wanted to add svg resizing to the charts to allow my charts to adjust automatically.  For most of my charts, this works great, but I have a problem with the brush windows. When I use an SVG viewbox rather than explicitly using the parent sizes, then my brush region gets set to a small region of the overall svg (in my case the brush window is 300px x 150px area while the parent d3G in code below is actually 1150*100).

Here are the code snippets for initializing the chart and the brush window in a manner that works correctly:

```
  this.width = this.parentNativeElement.offsetWidth - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
  this.height = this.parentNativeElement.offsetHeight - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

          this.d3G = this.d3.select(this.parentNativeElement).append('svg')
//change in the next two attr lines
            .attr('width', this.parentNativeElement.offsetWidth)
            .attr('height', this.parentNativeElement.offsetHeight)
            .append<SVGElement>('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin.left + ',' + this.margin.top + ')');

     // ... some other initialization here (scale, domain, line drawing functions etc)

        this.d3G.append('g')
          .attr('class', 'brush')
          .call(this.d3.brushX().on('end',  () => this.brushed() )
```

For all of my charts, the only real change I needed to make was to change the 'width' and 'height' attr lines and replace them with:

```
.attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + this.parentNativeElement.offsetWidth + ' ' + this.parentNativeElement.offsetHeight)
.attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'none')
.attr('width', '100%')
```

I have seen other posts about issues initializing the Extents on Firefox: https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/issues/13, but I am not setting extents, I am having errors with the default height and width settings. This is also occurring on Chrome, not firefox.

I do not have any issues with the default height and width setting for any other svg subsets, only the brush window.

I also have verified that I do not have any static css settings that would define a static window size.  The Google devtools show the height and width are auto/auto on that element as well.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to have a fairly trivial fix.  Apparently, the brush does not accept default (from parent) settings to initialize both height and width.  If I set one, and then use 100% of the other, then that is enough information for the brush to initialize correctly.  Here is ultimately what I used for configuring the resizing:

```
.attr('width', '100%')
.attr('height', this.parentNativeElement.offsetHeight)
.attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + this.parentNativeElement.offsetWidth + ' ' + this.parentNativeElement.offsetHeight)
.attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'none')
```

This results in an svg that maintains a static height, and scales only in the horizontal direction, but does not have any issues with the brush.